# Style a php value in a PHP mail form

Tags: php, css

I need help with styling a code line in a php mail form file.
So I have a translation file (see example below) that i use to translate text in the webpage incl, the mail form.
This works fine. But can any one tell me how can I style the text that is shown in the email, based on the code below?

It is this line I want to style so that the text in the email is shown as bold and red:
You can see that I'm getting the text translation here: `$words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']` the last part is just a fall back function.

**It is about the following line:**
`$message_body = isset($words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']) ? $words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']."\r\n\n" : "A new message from FCAB-Website. Information below.\r\n\n";`

You will find this code on line 52.
In short I want to surround this code with a style.

```
/*----------------------------------Translation file start----------------------------------*/

<?php

$words = array(
    "en" => array(
        'EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE' => "New message from FCAB-Website. Information below."
    ),

/*---------------End English Translation - Start Swedish Translation------------------------*/

    "se" => array(
        'SOME_TEXT' => "Nytt meddelande från FCAB-Hemsida. Information nedan."),
    );

?>

/*----------------------------------Translation file end-----------------------------------*/  
/*----------------------------------Form process file start--------------------------------*/

<?php 
include_once 'translation-file.php';

/* Some code goes here */
/* Email function start*/
/* I WANT TO STYLE THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW HERE SO THAT IN THE EMAIL THIS TEXT WILL BE BOLD AND RED*/

/*-->This line--->*/
$message_body = isset($words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']) ? $words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']."\r\n\n" : "A new message from FCAB-Website. Information below.\r\n\n";

    unset($_POST['submit']);

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .=  "$key: $value\r\n\n";
    }

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: ".$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $to = 'patrik@fcab.se';
    $subject = isset($words[$lang]['CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT']) ? $words[$lang]['CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT'] : "FCAB-Homepage. New message.";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body, $headers)){
        $success = isset($words[$lang]['CONTACT_THANKYOU']) ? $words[$lang]['CONTACT_THANKYOU'] : "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
        $name = $email = $company = $message = $website = '';

    }

?>

/*----------------------------------Form process file end--------------------------------*/
```

Comment: You can just use style as you use in html page: $message_body = isset($words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']) ? "<span style='color:red'>".$words[$lang]['EMAIL_RECIVE_MESSAGE']."\r\n\n</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>A new message from FCAB-Website. Information below.\r\n\n</span>";

Comment: Thank you i just solved it.